# Using a custom function expecting a vector with mutate and group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to run a custom function that uses specific columns of a dataframe split by groups. Here is my sample data & function code:

```
 my_data = data.frame(N = c(12, 12, 24, 24, 12, 12),
                     p = rep(c(.125,.125,.025),2),
                     group = rep(c("dogs","cats"),each=3))

power.sequential <- function(d, nseq, pseq){
  decvec <- NULL
  nvec <- NULL
  for (i in 1:100){
    decvec[i] <- 0
    nvec[i] <- 0
    j <- 1
    x <- NULL
    while(decvec[i] == 0 & nvec[i] < sum(nseq)){
      x <- c(x, rnorm(nseq[j], mean = d))
      p <- t.test(x)$p.value
      nvec[i] <- nvec[i] + nseq[j]
      if (p < pseq[j]) decvec[i] <- 1
      j <- j + 1      
    }
  }
  power <- mean(decvec == 1)
  meanN <- mean(nvec)
  return(list("power" = power, "mean_N" = meanN))
}
```

Now I want to run this function on each group in my dataframe. This is how the function is called normally:

```
power.sequential(d = .5,
                 nseq = c(12,12,24),
                 pseq = c(.125,.125,.025))
```

The function returns two values, and ideally they would each be saved in a separate column of my dataframe.
And this is my best try, but it gives an error message:

```
my_data %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(result = power.sequential(d=.5,nseq=N,pseq=p))
```

I probably need to reshape my dataframe so that each group is a single row, but I'm stuck on how to proceed.

Here is my desired output, the function outputs two values (power and meanN), each should get its own column.

```
group power meanN
 dogs  .94   20.28
 cats  .95   27.36
```

Comment: Can you show us your desired output?

Comment: Your function is returning a list of two means. `mean` will accept a vector answer, but always return a scalar result. Do you really want two columns of a scalar result?

Comment: Yes, I would like two separate columnsin my output. It's possible that it would be easier to tweak how the function outputs the values.

Comment: @Esther I should appreciate the code/details provided with question. It helped me to get the answer quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
my_data %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 do(data.frame(power.sequential(d=.5,nseq=.$N,pseq=.$p)[c(1, 2)])) %>%
 data.frame()
```

That gives:

```
  group power mean_N
1  cats  0.96  27.24
2  dogs  0.94  21.12
```

Comment: power and mean_N are stored as a list in the dataframe, is there a way to get them to a numeric vector in the code above? Else what I'm doing is just converting them by using as.numeric()

Answer (score 1):

The task can be simplified with use of `data.table`. One can call the function in 'j` section directly and both values will appear as separate column.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(my_data)
set.seed(1)
my_data[,power.sequential(0.5, N, p), by=group]

# group power mean_N
# 1:  dogs  0.90  24.48
# 2:  cats  0.94  27.72
```

**Note**: `set.seed(1)` has been used to keep the result consistent.